# Change Marker icon depending on state correctly?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am able to draw a Marker based upon a state (e.g. a field within my extended `OverlayItem` class) using the following code :

```
@Override
public Drawable getMarker(int pStateBitset)
{
  Drawable currentMarker = super.getMarker(pStateBitset);

  Drawable[] toDrawLayers;
  if (mSelected)
  {
    BitmapDrawable overlay = (BitmapDrawable) mSELECTED_OVERLAY;
    overlay.setAntiAlias(true);

    toDrawLayers = new Drawable[] { currentMarker, overlay };
  }
  else
  {
    toDrawLayers = new Drawable[] { currentMarker };
  }

  return new LayerDrawable(toDrawLayers);     
}
```

This works as expected (drawing a marker such as [image: Actual marker]). The glow of the marker is the effect I wish to achieve. As per the code above, it is generated via two layered `Drawable`s, namely (for instance) [image: School Marker] and [image: Marker Overlay] .

I had to ensure that the size of the glow is the same as the normal marker image, so that the resulting `Drawable` doesn't rescale (marker image size is 32x37 px).

However, what I am aiming for is in fact a bigger glow (that would, indeed yield a bigger image), such as : [image]

How can I render a drawable which yields a bigger glow (thus using an image which is indeed bigger than the normal marker image) and does *not* result in a scaled / resized normal marker ? Is that feasable ?

Thanks in advance, I can provide any additional details if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different marker image. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk) showing changing the marker image based on user input.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I know how that can be achieved, I've listed my code above. I was wondering if there was a way of applying the glow without having to make yet another version (via Photoshop Actions and so on) of the 30+ markers, resulting in more overhead in the 'res/drawable' dir.

Comment: @Dr1Ku: Add more transparent pixels around the relevant edges of your base image, enough to hold your larger glow. Apply an appropriately-sized glow via a `LayerListDrawble`.